# How do you add a listing of all the files in your directory to a text file ?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I have a text file in my directory called `mytextfile.txt`  ,  and I would like to add a listing of all the files in my current directory to the existing contents of that text file.

I tried this :

```
ls >>  `mytextfile.txt`
```

but this doesn't work .  I even tried `ls -a` but that also doesn't work

Comment: Why not? What happened?

Comment: @SLaks - well, it just said "wrong answer"   (this for a test i'm taking)

Comment: You're misunderstanding backticks.

Comment: and backticks aren't needed for your problem. Just remove them and your cmd should work (If I understand your requirement). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much all

Answer (score 2):

You dont need the backticks

```
ls >>  mytextfile.txt
```